# How can I restore my Vista PATH environment variable when System Restore is not available?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, environment-variables, system-restore

After installing IShadow I found out that my PATH environment variable was changed from some 20 paths to only one path: `c:\program files\ishadow\system32`. Many Windows tools stopped working, well known commands in the command prompt could not be found, Visual Studio SDK didn't work anymore etc etc.

The bad news: I found out too late and I don't have a system restore that goes back to before installing the (extremely bad behaving) [IShadow Desktop](http://www.ishadow.com/tabid/104/Default.aspx). The owning company does not respond to my queries.

<strike>Another result is that Windows Backup fails with error 0x80080005 which I reckon also has to do with the paths not being correct.</strike> EDIT: that error was not related, but a [result of wrong ACL on `System Volume Information`](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2010/07/solving-error-0x80080005-of-windows-backup/).

Any idea on how to restore the PATH? What are common paths that should go in there, after `c:\windows`? Can someone lookup his/her own list, esp. the first few, for me? It would be great if you could include the Windows SDK / .NET SDK paths as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System path contains the following general entries for 32-bits Windows which might apply in your case:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

However, many entries in System and Local paths pertain to products you have installed. You might have no choice but to reinstall these products that don't work.

I note that an excellent utility for editing the two paths is [System Path Commander](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Other/Spc/index.html) by donationcoder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I missed the Wbem. I also needed to add `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools` and `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\VCPackages` for Visual Studio, `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` and `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` for .NET and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin` for the Windows / .NET SDK (repeated here because .NET, VS and SDK are common enough)